# Нужна ли запятая после "но" перед "чем"?

Tags: пунктуация

Но(,) чем дольше он думал, тем больше появлялась четкая уверенность, что не стоит делать поспешных выводов. 
Почему-то хочется поставить запятую...

Answer (score 4):

Запятую лучше не ставить: **Но чем дольше он думал, тем больше появлялась четкая уверенность, что не стоит делать поспешных выводов.**

В приведенном примере запятая нежелательна, так как союз ЧЕМ...ТЕМ **является двойным.** А вообще говоря, запятая чаще не ставится после присоединительных **союзов И, А**, ставится после **союза ОДНАКО**, а **после союза НО** ставится факультативно.

Обычно нет необходимости  в постановке запятой после  присоединительных союзов перед подчинительными союзами, так как при авторском обособлении союза  придаточная часть приобретает **вставочный характер**.

Пример

**Но чем** больше прачка всматривалась в картину, **тем** понятнее становилось ей, что это точно тот дом, откуда исчезла злополучная крона. [А. С. Грин. Акварель (1929)

Розенталь (о присоединительных союзах): [§110. Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://tepka.ru/rozental_2/110.html)